# OSX (Macbook) saving to subfolders

Tags: macos

I am using Yosemite. When I wish to save a file or other to the file system I always get offered "Documents" folder and there is no option to select a subfolder. How can subfolders be configured?

Answer (score 1):

[Take a look](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/484921?start=0&tstart=0):

> Go in the dialog box next to space where you type the name to save it
>   as. There should be a buttion with a small arow pointing down. Pushit
>   and it lets you choose the exact place to save a file.

Comment: I would if it was obvious what to click!

Comment: I would mark an answer as solved if I could see how to do it"